# Размещение Tablayout снизу

Tags: android, android-layout, разметка, android-tablayout

Как `Tablayout` расположить снизу? Сверху нету проблем, а вот если помещаю после `viewpager`то `viewpager` занимает весь экран. Да я могу указать `viewPager` размер, а как сделать чтоб его размер от Tablayout строился

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpPager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="33dp">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте вес для верхнего элемента, не для корневого так:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpPager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="33dp">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает для меня))